# What is the reason behind black hole making objects near him dissappear?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, singularities

If a [black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) is formed by the death of a star, why does it suck things with its gravity going inside it? Does it not have a surface or anything? Is it just a hole in the space which keeps on attracting things and making them disappear?

Comment: welcome  here though I think the site is way over your background. Black holes are a solution of general realtivity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! What are your thoughts? Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question. And it's important to detail where you're stuck and why, in order to attract good answers. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Black hole is not an empty thing - it is lot of mass in the (relatively) tiny sphere.

The radius of this sphere is different for different black holes - say from atomic diameter to hundreds of kilometers. You may calculate it from the mass of the black hole by the formula

$$ r = {GM \over c^2}$$
where G is the gravitational constant, M is mass, and c is the speed of light.

---

*Note:*

The radius of a black hole is defined as the distance from its *event horizon* to its center. The event horizon is - roughly speaking - the place in which we are able still see the light not consumed by this black hole.

Comment: Your radius range is not supported by observation. There is no evidence that atomic size black holes exist. The smallest observed black hole has the horizon radius of several kilometers. The largest one is billions of kilometers in size, not hundreds.

Comment: @safesphere, thanks, you are highly likely correct, I'm not a specialist for black holes. This is the reason for the word “say” in my answer.

Comment: @MarianD "Black hole is not an empty thing - it is lot of mass in the (relatively) tiny sphere." The Schwarzschild solution for black holes is a vacuum solution of Einsteins field equations (stress-energy tensor is identical zero). So this (mathematical) black hole is empty. The mass is contained in the singularity which is not part of the manifold. In contrast an "astrophysical black hole" is believed to contain mass of unknown nature in the center.

Answer (score 0):

As you see from the comments, black holes are a solution of GR.

You are asking why they keep attracting things. The answer is stress-energy (not mass contrary to popular belief). Though, this could be true for any kind of star, that keeps attracting things. Why are black holes special?

There are a few reasons:

1. black holes are black because nothing (not even visible light can escape them), the theoretical escape velocity inside the event horizon exceeds the speed of light
2. they are the only things (objects in space) with a event horizon, that is a boundary that separates a region based on escape velocity of light, or more rigorously, inside the horizon, no event can affect observers outside the horizon
3. it is in many ways the only ideal black object, emitting no light
4. there is a general consensus that supermassive black holes exist in the center of most galaxies

The reason we see black holes is because of the accretion disk they have around, heated by friction. We also can calculate the objects' orbital data around the black hole to determine its mass and location.

Now, the reason black holes make things disappear near them is they have a stress-energy so huge, they make all objects around them inevitably fall into them (because they cirve spacetime so much), and eventually as these objects pass the event horizon, become invisible (since no light can escape the black hole).

You are asking whether black holes have a surface, and the answer is no, but we can interpret the event horizon as some kind of surface. Though, an observer falling through the event horizon does not notice anything special. The observer might not even realize he has passed the event horizon.

Comment: @safesphere thank you I edited.

Comment: @Árpád Szendrei Thanks!, but i wanted to ask can we think that the objects near a blackhole are also behaving like the planets around the sun? But we cant see anything because not even light can escape.

Comment: @AbdulWasay planets (and other objects like stars) can and sometimes do orbit black holes, but the reason we do not see them is not because of the black hole's gravity. we just cannot see the black hole itself (or anything that enters the event horizon). anything that is outside the event horizon is visible (if it emits light like a star).

Comment: @AbdulWasay Stars orbiting the supermassive black hole called Sagittarius A* in the center of our Milky Way galaxy: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/Galactic_centre_orbits.svg/1280px-Galactic_centre_orbits.svg.png

Comment: @Árpád Szendrei And what all of a sudden gave rise to event horizon if before its formation, their was only a massive star made of dust and gases? What exactly gave rise to the blackhole? An explosion(supernova)? Which all of a sudden made it look like a dark star with gravity so powerful?

Comment: @AbdulWasay yes, there is a solution to GR, where the stress-energy (not mass) of the object (supermassive star) is so great, that it curves spacetime so much, that the curvature will cause the theoretical escape speed exceed the speed of light. The boundary of that curvature limit is the event horizon. Inside the horizon, the curvature causes the theoretical escape speed to exceed c, while outside the horizon, the curvature is not so great. I would not call it an explosion. It is a collapse.

Comment: @AbdulWasay Normally, EM force and the strong force (and weak) can withstand gravity (which is the weakest force in short range), so there is matter building up our world. Now when gravity becomes enormous, it overcomes the EM, strong (and weak) forces on the short range, and matter collapses. As matter collapses, it will occupy a smaller volume, and thus it will cause extreme curvature. This extreme curvature starts there where the event horizon is.

Comment: Thanks! then what made the gravity so enormous only the death of a star?

Comment: @AbdulWasay it is called a neutron star, and this is the only way to create such a dense material (neutrons) packed into such a small volume of space and time. Actually it is more complicated, because the neutrons cannot occupy the same quantum states as per the Pauli exclusion principle, but when all quantum states are fully packed by neutrons in the smallest volume possible, then it collapses.

Comment: You mean a neutron star give rise to a blackhole?

Comment: @AbdulWasay yes, the neutron star collapses, creating enormous curvature, and creating an event horizon, and a black hole.

Comment: Why do people relate time travel with blackholes? i dont see any reason why it must be related with that.

Comment: @AbdulWasay the reason is because theoretically, the curvature of spacetime is so enormous that it could create a wormhole, thus connecting two distant points in spacetime. But this is not really time travel, more like a jump in spacetime. Theoretical timetravel (backwards) would require a speed exceeding the speed of light.

Comment: Yeah i also know that time will go backwards if we pass the speed of light and will stop for us if we travel at the speed of light. But how can this be called time travelling?

Comment: @Árpád Szendrei "The answer is stress-energy (not mass contrary to popular belief)." No, see my comment for MarianD. The answer is space-time curvature due to the mass in the singularity.

Comment: @timm spacetime curvature is not caused by mass (it is caused by stress-energy)

Comment: @Árpád Szendrei: No, its a vacuum solution as I said in the other comment. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_solution_(general_relativity) " According to the Einstein field equation, this means that the stress–energy tensor also vanishes identically, so that no matter or non-gravitational fields are present."